# R bigmemory attach.big.matrix is very slow for very wide matrices

Tags: r, matrix, bigdata, r-bigmemory

I am using the package bigmemory to interact with large matrices in R.  This works well for large matrices except that the `attach.big.matrix()` function to reload a binary file created with `read.big.matrix()` is MUCH slower than the original call to `read.big.matrix()`.  Here is an example:

```
library(bigmemory)

# Create large matrix with 1,000,000 columns
X = matrix(rnorm(1e8), ncol=1000000)

colnames(X) = paste("col", 1:ncol(X))
rownames(X) = paste("row", 1:nrow(X))

# Write to file
write.big.matrix(as.big.matrix(X), "X.txt", row.names=TRUE, col.names=TRUE)

# read into big.matrix and create backing-file for faster loading the second time
A = read.big.matrix("X.txt", header=TRUE, has.row.names=TRUE, type="double", backingfile="X.bin", descriptorfile="X.desc")

# Attach the data based on the backing-file 
G = attach.big.matrix("X.desc")
```

When the number of columns is small (i.e. 1000), the code works as expected and `attach.big.matrix()` is faster than `read.big.matrix()`.  But with 1,000,000 columns, `attach.big.matrix()` is 10x slower!

Also, note that this performance issue completely goes away when there are no column names (i.e. comment-out the `colnames(X)` line) and I can attach in zero time.  This suggestions that the bottle neck is in parsing `X.desc` and there should be a better way to `attach.big.matrix()`.

This matrix is small in comparison to my real data.

Or can I do something different?

Thanks

System info:

Intel Xeon E5-2687W @ 3.10GHz with 64 Gb RAM

Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

R 3.0.1

bigmemory_4.4.3

Answer (score 0):

From the package [user manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/bigmemory.pdf)

> If x has a huge number of rows and/or columns, then the use of rownames and/or colnames will
>   be extremely memory-intensive and should be avoided.

As you suggest yourself the performance issue disappears when you avoid using column names. In my case I solve this by keeping column names in a separate vector that I use to extract the indices of the columns I need.